# Error- when trying to find incomplete cases

Tags: r

I have a tfidf tokens dataframe

```
dim(twit.tokens.tfidf)
#23871 2360148
```

When I do the following :

```
# Check for incompllete cases.
incomplete.cases <- which(!complete.cases(twit.tokens.tfidf))
```

I get the error :

> Error in complete.cases(twit.tokens.tfidf) : invalid 'type' (S4) of argument

Can someone guide me as to what could be the problem here?

Comment: The function is expecting input of different class. Can you share output of `class(twit.tokens.tfidf)` ?

Comment: The command class(twit.tokens.tfidf) returns: [1] "dfm"
attr(,"package")
[1] "quanteda"